# QueryDSL PathBuilder discover property type and existence

Tags: querydsl

Can anyone tell me how do I check the existence of a property via PathBuilder?

I am aware that there's a protected method validate() in PathBuilder but it can't be overriden 'cause PathBuilder is a final class.

Assuming that I have a model class called Person:

```
    PathBuilder<?> entityPath = new PathBuilder<Person>(Person.class, "person");

    PathBuilder<?> propertyPath = path.get("name");
```

I also need to get the type of a property via PathBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

QueryDSL 3.3.1 fixed that issue (See [release notes](http://www.querydsl.com/releases)). PathBuilder is not final any more and you can override the validate() method.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. PathBuilder is not tied to a certain property scheme such as java bean properties, it just provides a fluent API to create Path instances dynamically.

What you are searching for might be Java Bean introspection.